# Подскажите как в боте telegram редактировать гиперссылку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Суть такая - изучаю Python, занялся написанием своего первого бота в Telegram.

Использую библиотеку: `pyTelegramBotAPI`.

Суть проблемы следующая - при написании этого кода в телеграм боте при старте вылетает мое сообщение следующего вида:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '[Кликабельный текст](https://ссылка)'.format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='Markdown')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы текст был исключительно таким?:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите параметр `disable_web_page_preview`.

***Пример:***

```py
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '[Кликабельный текст](https://ссылка)'.format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='Markdown', disable_web_page_preview=True)
```